# How to add a Button to a HeaderSpan in SmartGWT?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to add a Button to a HeaderSpan in SmartGWT. At start, the title of the button will be + (Plus), when the user clicks the button, all the rows of the table are shown and the title of the Button becomes - (Minus). There are around 25 columns in the `ListGrid` hence I want this behaviour.

I have tried using the `HeaderSpan.setAttribute("button", new Button("+"))` method but it did not work. Please help.

Any other approach to hide/unhide columns will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've watched this [link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_header_spans). As per the overview given in the screen, it does provide hide/show of particular column as well as particular headerspan. On right side of each column a dropdown like button is given which is visible on mouse over & serves your purpose. If you want to change it's icon, you can try the following code, where **headerMenuButtonIcon** is the path of your image:

```
grid.setHeaderMenuButtonIcon(headerMenuButtonIcon);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello Trans, I've modified my answer. Now I hope this may help you.